# скрипт на удаление всего форматирования с листа

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Я уверен, что есть такой скрипт на удаления всего форматирования с листа. Писал макрос на удаления форматирования в гугл таблицах, очень долго работает, пытался сам написать скрипт, не понимаю и не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации, используйте `.clearFormats()` для очистки листа от форматирования, сохранив при этом данные на этом листе:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
first.clearFormats();
```

Если необходимо очистить правила условного форматирования, то используйте `clearConditionalFormatRules()`. Пример:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
```